# Three JS animation in Editor possible?

Tags: animation, three.js, collada

I have been able to get almost everything I need into the editor, But cannot figure out how to get a collada model that was imported to play it's keyframes. 
Since I am not doing loader.load (collada) blah blah like in the examples. I cannot figure out how to get the animations. Animations is always undefined, but I know keyframes exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, animations in the editor are not fully implemented yet.
the corresponding [code in the viewport](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/Viewport.js) is commented out (line564+)

i think your best shot is to modify the editor (and eventually create a PR) or go back to coding everything.

the editor in its current form only shows the basic functions but the code is quite well structured to allow implementing custom features.

Comment: i usually tend to modify the editor/js/libs/app.js. it has far less code than the editor itself & it is all in one place. it runs when pressing play and can be reused when publishing the file. it is the least effort & change while keeping most benefits of the editor. also it has a constant (60fps) loop while the editor renders event-based. so it will be better for animations

Answer (score 0):

A quick update that animations in the Three.js Editor are [now supported](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15698). Below is a gif from the linked PR demonstrating usage.

[image: animation in editor]

Comment: I am currently using editor r150, but there's nothing below the `User data` box. Is there any special way to enable animation, or has this option vanished again ?